# Number in query string translated to different value

Tags: javascript, asp.net, iis-7.5

I inherited an old ASP website that uses JavaScript to open a small window:

```
<a href="javascript:OpenBillBack(961,0011)">OPEN</a>

function OpenBillBack(RequestID, Process) {
    BillbackUrl = "Billback.aspx?Request_ID=" + RequestID + "&PR=" + Process;
    mywin = window.open(BillbackUrl, "BillBack", "target=_blank,height=450,width=555,top=200,left=200,status=no,toolbar=no,scrollbars=no,menubar=no,location=no,resizable=yes");
    mywin.focus();
}
```

However, in the window that opens the value for the `PR` parameter has somehow been translated from "0011" to "9":

http://myurl.com/Billback.aspx?Request_ID=961&PR=9

So far, I believe this is related to the leading zeros in the parameter value, since other links with non-leading zero values do not experience the same behavior.

What is it about the leading zeros that would cause this translation?  Or is that a red herring?

This is running in ASP.NET 4.0 Classic on IIS 7.5.

Comment: 0011 octal (i.e. base 8) is 9 - **numbers** beginning with `0` that don't have any digit > 7 are treated as octals ...

Comment: Change those arguments to Strings, by putting them in quotes.